# How Webpack bundle in production mode?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp

I am trying to bundle my React application for development with Webpack via Gulp.  After bundling, in Chrome the "React Development Tools" toolbar is red and tells me "This page is using the development build of React.".  How do I bundle using the production version?

From package.json:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-webpack": "^1.5.0",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
"webpack": "^2.6.1"
```

Here is the gulp command:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

gulp.task('webpack', function(){
  return gulp.src('public_html/app/back/js/all.jsx')
    .pipe(webpack(webpackConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app/back/js'));
});
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './public_html/app/back/js/all.jsx',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}dist/app/back/js`,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your plugins array in your WebPack code you need to add the following

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  beautify: false,
  mangle: {
    screw_ie8: true,
    keep_fnames: true
  },
  compress: {
    screw_ie8: true,
  },
  comments: false,
}),
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work.  The React toolbar is still red with the same message.  The console says:  `Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. See _facebook-link_ for more details.` . It has changed something as the gulp output has changed ("Condition always false", "Dropping unreachable code", etc).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: are you using ```-p``` flag with your webpack script?

Comment: I'm running webpack via gulp (not npm)... where would i put `-p`?

Comment: something like this in your npm ```scripts``` ```"client-development": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js --colors -p",```

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, I'm not using `npm`, I'm using `gulp`.  My `gulpfile.js` and `webpack.config.js` are included above ... not sure if I can add that flag in there somewhere?  Googling hasnt helped.